# AWSにデプロイしたRailsのアプリがブラウザで表示できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

## 環境

Amazon linux
Rails 6.0.2.1
Ruby 2.6.3
nginx
unicorn
mysql

## 実現したいこと

現在、以下の記事を参考に、EC2を用いてRailsアプリをAWSにデプロイしています。
https://qiita.com/naoki_mochizuki/items/5a1757d222806cbe0cd1
現在はnginx、unicornの設定と起動まで行いました。
手順通りであれば、ブラウザにアプリが表示される段階です。

## 発生しているエラー

ブラウザで当該IPにアクセスしても接続が拒否されてしまい、表示されません。
解決法をご存知の方がいればご教授いただきたく思います。
[image: curlでの確認]

## 設定

unicorn

```
  # set lets
  $worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/portgram"
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir
  # set config
  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  # after finishing processes
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

nginx

```
# log directory
error_log  /var/www/rails/portgram/log/nginx.error.log;
access_log /var/www/rails/portgram/log/nginx.access.log;
# max body size
client_max_body_size 2G;
upstream app_server {
  # for UNIX domain socket setups
  server unix:/var/www/rails/portgram/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 18.181.56.156;
  # nginx so increasing this is generally safe...
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  # path for static files
  root /var/www/rails/portgram/public;
  # page cache loading
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  location @app {
    # HTTP headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
  # Rails error pages
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/rails/portgram/public;
```

また、（自分のアプリ名）/log/nginx.error.log及び（自分のアプリ名）/log/unicorn.logと（自分のアプリ名）/log/production.logも確認しましたが、エラーは出ていませんでした。

セキュリティグループの設定については、以下の通りです。
[image: AWSインバウンド1]
[image: AWSインバウンド2]

## 試したこと

下記の記事を参考にしましたが、改善されませんでした。

https://qiita.com/sakaimo/items/dd138b39c7480fb2ebff
https://qiita.com/shinyashikis@github/items/ace49154f0c71c65b2c9

上記以外には、config/environments/production.rbの
config.assets.compile = trueの部分をfalseに変更も試しました。

他にも引き続きエラーの解消に向けて調査を続けていますがいまだに手がかりをつかめません。
加えて、エラー文が見つけられないのでさらに原因の特定に時間がかかってしまっています。
どんな情報でもいいのでアドバイスいただければと思っています。
よろしくお願いします。

## 追記

以下のコマンドを試したところ、port22と80は繋がります。
443だけやはり弾かれる状態のようです。
[image: portチェック]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://qiita.com/naoki_mochizuki/items/5a1757d222806cbe0cd1
この記事ではHTTPSでの接続は考慮されてないように見えます。
それを承知でHTTPSでつなぎたい場合の話になります。

nginxのコンフィグで443の設定がされていないように見えます。
また443(HTTPS)を使いたい場合、SSL証明書が必要になります。let's encryptを使うのが手っ取り早いと思います。
またSSL証明書を使うときはドメイン名が必要になります。適宜用意してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。さっそくnginxで443のポートを使う設定に変更したところ、ブラウザのエラーメッセージが「このサイトは安全に接続できません」に変わりました。あとはSSLの証明書を設定すれば表示できるという解釈でいいでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。SSL証明書の追加に関しては、Let's Encrypt で Nginx にSSLを設定する - Qiita https://qiita.com/HeRo/items/f9eb8d8a08d4d5b63ee9　を参考にしてください。

Comment: 確認ありがとうございます。ひとまずこの質問で解決したい事については解消できました。また別のエラーが出ましたがそちらについてはしばらく自分で対応してみます。